# Sending string of HTML to a server, can I then interact with it using a DOM? Is it possible to use jQuery on it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

Say the following HTML is part of a webpage -

```
<div id='container'>
    <div class='inner'>
        <p id='text_a'>Some text</p>
        <p id='text_b'>Some more text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Say I save this HTML into a string and send it to a server. Is it possible then to interact with this HTML on the server using a DOM? So that I can do something like .getElementById('text_a').value to retrieve 'Some text'? And following on, would it be possible to use jQuery to interact with the HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio). From the readme:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    $ = cheerio.load('<h2 class="title">Hello world</h2>');

$('h2.title').text('Hello there!');
$('h2').addClass('welcome');

$.html();
//=> <h2 class="title welcome">Hello there!</h2>
```

There's also [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), but cheerio is simpler and comes with jquery-like goodness.

Answer (score -1):

The DOMDocument class

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

3rd party

PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm